# How to make WPF scrollviewer smoother

Tags: wpf

I'm using a scrollviewer like this:

```
<ScrollViewer PanningMode="Both" >
    <TextBlock FontSize="15" TextWrapping="Wrap">         
       (a block of random text)
    </TextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I am using a very decent new laptop with a touchscreen but if I flick the text, the movement is not nice, it is jerky. If I use any windows 8 apps with touching / flicking etc the movement is silky smooth.

Is this an issue with WPF? Is there any way to get smooth scrolling?

Thanks

Comment: Check out my blog post on this topic here: http://blog.mingslogar.com/posts/2013/05/01.php. It does not directly solve your problem, but may provide you with ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` is set to `false`.

```
<ScrollViewer PanningMode="Both" CanContentScroll=false>
    <TextBlock FontSize="15" TextWrapping="Wrap">         
       (a block of random text)
    </TextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```

> ### Physical vs. Logical Scrolling
>
> Physical scrolling is used to scroll content by a predetermined
>   physical increment, typically by a value that is declared in pixels.
>   Logical scrolling is used to scroll to the next item in the logical
>   tree. Physical scrolling is the default scroll behavior for most Panel
>   elements. WPF supports both types of scrolling.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Alternatively, you could try this fella:

> ### SurfaceScrollViewer Class
>
> Users can flick the content of a SurfaceScrollViewer control by
>   touching the control, rapidly moving their finger a short distance,
>   and then lifting their finger. When their finger is lifted, the
>   content of the SurfaceScrollViewer control continues to move. The
>   content then decelerates and comes to a stop. You can programmatically
>   stop the movement caused by flicking by calling the StopFlick method.
>
> You can manipulate the content of a SurfaceScrollViewer either by
>   moving a scroll bar (like with the WPF SurfaceScrollViewer) or by
>   direct touch interaction with the content itself. The ability to
>   manipulate the content directly is called panning. By default, panning
>   is enabled. You can disable it by setting the IsManipulationEnabled
>   property to false.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.surfacescrollviewer.aspx
>   [(Archived link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130116192407/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.surfacescrollviewer.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I tried  CanContentScroll=false and true but it did not seem to make any difference. Also tried SurfaceScrollViewer.It is usable but just slightly unpleasant and nowhere near as good as windows 8.